# Decomposition of the spectrum of an unbounded opeator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

The Wikipedia article on spectral decomposition, see here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator

says the following:

> A self-adjoint operator A on $H$ has pure point spectrum if and only if $H$ has an orthonormal basis ${e_i}_{i \in I}$ consisting of eigenvectors for A.

Why is this true? What is a reference for a proof? (Also to be sure, I guess that pure point spectrum means that the spectrum of the operator is equal to its eigenvalues.)

Comment: I am not finding where the cited Wikipedia page says what is quoted. In any case, it is not true. Cluster points of eigenvalues are in the spectrum, but not necessarily in the point spectrum. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, I linked the incorrect page. It's fixed now.

Comment: The cited lines are from the last section: "Pure point spectrum"

Comment: If this is wrong, then I guess the Wikipedia page needs to be edited.

Comment: . . . . perhaps the question shouldn't be closed until we are sure it's not true?

Comment: On the wikipedia page this seems to be a definition of "pure point spectrum". So claiming whether it's true/false or asking for a proof is just pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it’s a matter of definitions. Here is from Kreyszig ([1978](//www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=467220), p. 521) (admittedly not covering the “unbounded” in your title):

[image: Kreyszig]